# Is there a fast way to find out presence of elements on form?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a form, which has many fields all of which are dynamic, i.e. fields are generated on basis of value selected in preceding field. At present I am waiting for each field, if it appears I fill it, otherwise I skip it. However, this has made the process very slow. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: You can override the wait command which might have been declared during the driver creation. You can reduce the time for waiting and then move to next field. Also fields may appear based on certain conditions. If you know the conditions then you can create code just for those fields and may not be necessary to wait for the fields.

Comment: In which browser and using what locator?

Comment: @Arran: In FF, I am using these locators: xpath, id, name linktext and css.

Comment: Decreased implicit wait to 1 sec. It improved the performance. Can not code on basis of conditions, because conditions can be altered by a back end interface. However I did include mandatory conditions to improve performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Vinay you can reduce certain amount of execution time but not entirely.

Does it not take time when you are testing it manually? If the total execution time for the scenario is taking more time than doing manually then this scenario is not a good candidate for automation. But if the time taken is less than doing manually then it is still worth spending.

Comment: As I mentioned performance improved by decreasing implicit wait. Yes time and effort taken is less than manual. I was talking about maximum efficiency. I think, as suggested by you guys this is the best performance that can be achieved in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the application speed. when you are able to do it in manual.It's possible in Automation too.We could reset the implicit wait time to speed up the process.

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Dont forget to set the time to use it again.